# Join to Domain Script - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, script, vbscript

I'm looking for a way to diss-join a machine from a domain and join a machine to a domain via scripts. I searched online and have found the following script that should join a machine to a domain but I can't seem to get it working or might just be executing it incorrectly.

```
Const JOIN_DOMAIN = 1
Const ACCT_CREATE = 2

strDomain = "domain"
strUser = "userAccount"
strPassword = "password"
strOU = "cn=COMPUTERS,dc=labtech,dc=COM"

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strComputer = objNetwork.ComputerName

Set objComputer = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=Impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" & strComputer & "'")

objComputer.JoinDomainOrWorkGroup strDomain, strPassword, strDomain & "\" & strUser, strOU, JOIN_DOMAIN + ACCT_CREATE
```

I know there is the powershell command of `add-computer` but from what I can see, there is no way to save the login credentials.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
-Matt

Comment: How ARE you trying to run it?  What happens when you do?  How about setting break points or logging various variables along the way so you can confirm they are getting the proper information.

Comment: I've used that exact code snippet in the past with success.

The account that you assign to the variables, have you verified that it can add computers to the domain manually? Also, have you tried to assign the strDomain variable the FQDN of your domain?

Comment: I was trying to execute it via wscript in cmd. The script would look like its running but not do anything. No error or status messages. I was able to get something similar working using Powershell. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to execute it via wscript in cmd. The script would look like its running but not do anything. No error or status messages. I was able to get something similar working using Powershell. Thanks guys.